# Why is my TrueType Font messing up in Acrobat 7.0 Professional

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, truetype, postscript

I have a PDF made (500 pages long) of different part numbers for my business, with their descriptions and prices. I'm using a truetype font so that fractions apear as actual fractions and not 1/8 with just a slash between the numbers. I have no problems until I get the PDF generated out of InDesign.

In Adobe Acrobat 7.0, Everything looks the way that it should look. But when I try and do a find for a part number that has 11 beside each other (like AMX10112) I can only highlight AMX101 and it will not let me highlight anymore of the number. Also, if I try to do a find for AMX10112 it will not find that number in the document.

Remaking the PDF does not help. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I read somewhere that beacuse TrueType fonts go through a PostScript something-or-other that it might be the reason behind my problems. Does anyone know if this is true, and how to fix it?

Comment: More: I'm exporting this PDF out of InDesign CS2. I'm using Franklin Gothic Medium Condensed and Franklin Gothic Demi Condensed. When they PDF is made and opened in Acrobat, I look to see what fonts are embedded and it has a crap ton more like Arial, Arial Narrow, Helvetic and everththing else. Everything is labeled as Embedded Subset or something like that. I don't even know if it is relevent to my problem.

Comment: If InDesign CS2 supports it, try exporting the file to a PDFA (or PDF/A) format file. Doing so should fix the searching problem (and perhaps the font subsetting problem as well).

Answer (score 0):

CS2 and Acrobat 7 are pretty old, so my first instinct would be to upgrade to something newer. But I realize that's not always feasible.

The fact that it isn't recognizing the "12" makes me wonder if internally it thinks that the "12" is really "1/2" or the "one-half character" (not to be confused with the characters [ '1', '/', '2' ]).

Embedding fonts increases the size of your PDF tremendously. It may also have copyright implications if you're using a font that is not licensed to the whole world for free. I would caution you against this and recommend just letting the PDF renderer on the clientside render it however it wants to. If you're really annoyed by getting EXACTLY the display you want, have it render to a bitmap -- but then you lose searching capabilities.

Seriously, for a PDF listing parts, is it really that important to display in a specific font?

Comment: I probably should have explained better. I am the Catalog designer for an Ag Replacement Parts company. The PDF is actually our Dealer Catalog with all our pricing and parts. It is what the Sales People use up front when they get phone calls. Which is why I really need to figure out why all of a sudden it will not find certain numbers. I've worked here for 9 months now, and this is the first time I've had this issue. I'm using STEP as my database and InDesign pulls all my information out of it. this version STEP will not work with Windows 7 and so I cannot upgrade at the current time.

Comment: So the actual font used is less important than being able to find the number quickly -- right? If that's the case, I would recommend not embedding fonts and just use the default; see if that helps.